# Apache Start Fails due to missing mpm module

Tags: linux, apache2, phpmyadmin, mpm-prefork

**I originally posted this question on StackOverflow. Before it was taken down as off topic, the answer and comments were leading to MPM not being loaded**

- I tried `sudo apt-get install apache-mpm-prefork` but was given the error:

  > E: Unable to locate package apache-mpm-prefork

**Below are all the steps I took today which led to the errors I am experiencing:**
 - Installing phpmyadmin following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04
 - I got stuck at `sudo phpenmod mcrypt` and `sudo phpenmod mbstring` as it was giving me some error
 - I then tried to diagnose this problem by creating a php file in var/www/html that simply contained `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
 - It was here that I saw that apache was not serving the php files as the webpage simply outputed `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
 - So I tried to follow this: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-apache-2-not-executing-php-files/
 - However this restarting was not working so I performed `sudo service apache2 stop` in hope that I could start again
 - `sudo service apache2 start` gives the error:

> Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

- Okay so `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` i guess:

  > - apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
  >     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  >     Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
  >            `-forking.conf
  >     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-11-25 09:21:39 PST; 2min 14s ago
  >     Process: 16632 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX apache2[16632]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX apache2[16632]: The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX apache2[16632]: Output of config test was:
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX apache2[16632]: AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX apache2[16632]: Action 'configtest' failed.
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX apache2[16632]: The Apache error log may have more information.
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
  >     Nov 25 09:21:39 XXXXXXXXXX systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
- I tried deleting what I changed in the config file but it still outputs the same

ANY help would be greatly appreciated; I really do not want to have to reinstall apache. Thanks.

> ### Current Config File (without comments)
>
> Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
>
> PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
>
> Timeout 300
>
> KeepAlive On
>
> MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
>
> KeepAliveTimeout 5
>
> User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
>   Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
>
> HostnameLookups Off
>
> ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
>
> LogLevel warn
>
> IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
>   IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
>
> Include ports.conf
>
> Options FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride None
>     Require all denied
>
> AllowOverride None
>     Require all granted
>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride None
>     Require all granted
>
> AccessFileName .htaccess
>
> Require all denied
>
> LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
>
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
>
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
>
> LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
>
> LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
>
> IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
>
> IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

Comment: I'm just wondering what is wrong with reinstalling Apache?

Comment: Is that really the simplest solution

Comment: I did not say that. I was just wondering why you explicitly stated that you don't want to reinstall. Can you share the Apache config without the comments?

Comment: Have you run journalctl -xe?

Comment: @Tom so I can figure out how to change config files in the future.

Comment: @Davidw That outputs, no journal files found.

Comment: Odd, there should be at least something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to serverfault!

As of Ubuntu 16.04 server the mpm-prefork module is included in the package apache2-bin. In order to install it you have to enter

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-bin
```

After that you will have to enable the mpm_prefork module like this:

```
sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

and then try again to start apache2:

```
sudo systemctl start apache2.service
```

The detailed error log is located here:

```
tail -n 50 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

journalctl and systemctl only give very basic information.

If you should furthermore have problems with installing the php modules mcrypt and mbstring then please post the complete error messages you get.

Hope this helps!